# Trying to delete a post using Blogger API returns "not found" error

Tags: python, api, blogger

Sending a DELETE request to Blogger REST API (v3.0), I'm trying to delete a post using [delete method](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#DeletingAPost). For this I use the following code:

```
api_uri = 'https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/%s/posts/%s' % (blogId, postId)
result = urlfetch.fetch(url=api_uri,
                  method=urlfetch.DELETE,
                  headers={'Authorization' : oauth_token})

self.response.out.write(result.content)
```

But the server returns:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

However, I can retrieve information about this post, using the following code:

```
api_uri = 'https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/%s/posts/%s' % (blogId, postId)
result = urlfetch.fetch(url=api_uri,
                  headers={'Authorization' : oauth_token})
self.response.out.write(result.content)
```

At this moment, I can't understand what am I doing wrong — the request is authorized, the `blogId` and `postId` are correct — but anyway, the server returns "not found" error.

If you know how to solve this problem or you can give useful advice — help me please. 
Thank you for your time and consideration of this matter.

**UPD 1:** If I send requests to the following URLs:

```
# https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/users/{userID}
# https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/users/self
```

The server also returns:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

**UPD 2:** I forgot to say that I'm using [OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount). Thus, to get authorization token, I send request to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` using the following JWT Claim Set:

```
jwt_claim_set = {
   'iss' : '{id}@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
   'scope' : 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger',
   'aud' : 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
   'exp' : expire,
   'iat' : timestamp
}
```

The server returns:

```
{
  "access_token" : "1/8xbJqaOZXSUZbHLl5EOtu1pxz3fmmetKx9W8CV4t79M",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600
}
```

And define variable `oauth_token`, using:

```
data = simplejson.loads(result.content)
oauth_token = data['token_type'] + ' ' + data['access_token']
```

Comment: Considering you may have already checked the ID's and the auth token, I suggest you to test your queries manually with [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL). Depending on the result, you will know if the problem is how you build you url, or something else...

Comment: @AlexisHuet, Thank you for suggestion, but anyway, I'm sure that the problem isn't in the URL. Surely, the problem is "something else".

Comment: Have you tried it with `requests`, to see if the problem is in the module you use?

Comment: Is it just deletes that are failing? Or do you have a similar problem with edits too?

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you're using OAuth2 properly? It seems to me that you're not properly logged in, and that's why you're getting those errors.

Try those same queries using Google OAuh2 Playground (https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/) and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for for message, but as I said, I'm trying to use OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Application. At this moment OAuth 2.0 Playground doesn't support this authorization method. As for properly using of OAuth2, I think, if something was wrong it would be to displayed an another error.

Comment: Why don't you try instead of adding the Authorization in the headers just add ?access_token=<token> in the URL? That's how I use to do it anyway.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#DeletingAPost), it is necessary to send `Authorization` header. Did you mean that you are using `access_token=<token>` with OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications?